# Unable to install certain R packages from GitHub

Tags: r, github, rstudio, devtools

I am trying to install a package from GitHub: https://github.com/NIB-SI/seekr

However, running

```
devtools::install_github("ablejec/seekr")
```

yields the following error

> ```
> Downloading GitHub repo NIB-SI/pisar@HEAD Error: Failed to install
> 'pisar' from GitHub:   input string 34 is invalid In addition: Warning
> message: In gsub("[^/]", "", file_list) :   unable to translate
> 'NIB-SI-pisar-33d70bb/devel/_Welcome -<c0> R packages.URL' to a wide
> string
> ```

Other people with the same setup (RStudio running on windows) are able to install this package, but I have a sneaking suspicion the error is UTF-8 related. I am able to load the package via the downloaded package as such:

```
library("seekr", lib.loc = "C:/localfolder/seekr")
```

I have filed this issue in the GitHub repo, but I have a feeling this is such a specific error that it might not be fixable in the near future.

For reference, my SessionInfo output is:

> ```
> R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
> (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
>
> locale: [1] C
>
> time zone: Europe/Paris tzcode source: internal
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages:  [1] seekr_0.1.0.9000 lubridate_1.9.2 
> forcats_1.0.0    stringr_1.5.0    dplyr_1.1.2      purrr_1.0.1     
> readr_2.1.4      tidyr_1.3.0       [9] tibble_3.2.1     ggplot2_3.4.2 
> tidyverse_2.0.0  jsonlite_1.8.5  
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] generics_0.1.3   
> utf8_1.2.3        stringi_1.7.12    hms_1.1.3         digest_0.6.31   
> magrittr_2.0.3    timechange_0.2.0   [8] grid_4.3.0       
> pkgload_1.3.2     fastmap_1.1.1     processx_3.8.1    pkgbuild_1.4.2  
> sessioninfo_1.2.2 urlchecker_1.0.1  [15] ps_1.7.5         
> promises_1.2.0.1  fansi_1.0.4       scales_1.2.1      cli_3.6.1       
> shiny_1.7.4       rlang_1.1.1       [22] crayon_1.5.2     
> ellipsis_0.3.2    munsell_0.5.0     withr_2.5.0       remotes_2.4.2   
> cachem_1.0.8      devtools_2.4.5    [29] tools_4.3.0       tzdb_0.4.0 
> memoise_2.0.1     colorspace_2.1-0  httpuv_1.6.11     curl_5.0.1      
> vctrs_0.6.2       [36] R6_2.5.1          mime_0.12        
> lifecycle_1.0.3   fs_1.6.2          htmlwidgets_1.6.2 usethis_2.2.0   
> miniUI_0.1.1.1    [43] pkgconfig_2.0.3   callr_3.7.3      
> pillar_1.9.0      later_1.3.1       gtable_0.3.3      glue_1.6.2      
> profvis_0.3.8     [50] Rcpp_1.0.10       tidyselect_1.2.0 
> rstudioapi_0.14   xtable_1.8-4      htmltools_0.5.5   compiler_4.3.0  
> prettyunits_1.1.1
> ```

Comment: You can probably install the package locally once you download it and delete the `devel` folder. However, this doesn’t explain *why* the installation fails.

Comment: Would writing `writeLines('LC_ALL="C.UTF-8"', con = "~/.Renviron")` help? (to do in your R console to update into your `.Renviron` file).

Comment: Just to narrow this down a little bit, do you get the same error from `remotes::install_github("NIB-SI/pisar")` ? (i.e., it looks like the issue might be with an upstream package?)  What does `traceback()` give you?

Comment: @VonC This did not help

Comment: @BenBolker Indeed, the same error comes with installing this package. traceback() outputs (Edited for length):

7: stop(remote_install_error(remotes[[i]], e))
6: value[[3L]](cond)
5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
4: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
3: tryCatch(res[[i]] <- install_remote(remotes[[i]], ...), error = function(e) {
       stop(remote_install_error(remotes[[i]], e))
   })

Comment: @VonC Update (also see comment below; I edited the .Renviron file and set LC_ALL = "English_United States.1252", and this did the trick and I was able to install both packages. Seems C.UTF-8 was already the default setting in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea to why the original encoding did not work?

The `English_United States.1252` locale uses [Windows-1252 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which is a character encoding of the Latin alphabet. That character encoding is a super set of ISO 8859-1, and it was the default in many Windows applications, so it is designed to be compatible with many older software packages.

When you [switch your locale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16347731/6309) to `English_United States.1252`, you are changing the way that R handles and interprets character strings. Some packages may have been designed with this encoding in mind, or they may include non-UTF-8 characters that cause problems when R tries to interpret them as UTF-8.
See "[How to change the locale of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54162357/6309)"

The fact that switching to this locale helped resolve your issue suggests that the `seekr` package (or possibly one of its dependencies) includes such non-UTF-8 characters.

For instance, I see [`Bioconductor/BiocManager`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiocManager/index.html), a dependency of [`seekr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seeker/index.html) is usually used with `LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252`, as illustrated in [issue 103](https://github.com/Bioconductor/BiocManager/issues/103).

Answer (score 4):

There are some non-UTF8 characters in the repo: I forked the repo and removed them. If you install pisar from jpmam1/pisar, instead of NIB-SI/pisar, i.e.

```
devtools::install_github("jpmam1/pisar")
```

Then, reinstall seekr with:

```
devtools::install_github("ablejec/seekr")
```

It should install without issue (I'll make a pull request to the NIB-SI/pisar repo if it solves your problem).

Comment: Hey, I’m not able to verify the fix at this moment but I will try it next week. I will reset the bounty so you can claim it if it works :)

Comment: No worries @IllimarRekand, I don't really care about SO points, I'm just here to learn and I'm happy to help. If my answer doesn't solve your problem (when you get a chance to verify it) then I guess we can try to troubleshoot it further and/or post another bounty to see what other solutions might be out there. This is a hard question though, as I'm not able to reproduce the problem, so hopefully this solves it! Good luck

Comment: Hey and thanks for the help! I'm able ot provide something of an update now; installing from jpmam1/pisar provides a new error:

`"Downloading GitHub repo jpmam1/pisar@HEAD
Error: Failed to install 'pisar' from GitHub:
  input string 34 is invalid
In addition: Warning message: 
In gsub("[^/]", "", file_list) :
  unable to translate 'jpmam1-pisar-950cbc3/devel/_Welcome -<c0> R `packages.URL' to a wide string" `

I assume there's a few characters left in UTF8 formatting?

Comment: OK, so another update: By editing the .Renviron file and setting `LC_ALL = "English_United States.1252"`, I was able to both install pisar and the seekr packages in RStudio. Originally, the .Renviron was set to `'LC_ALL = C.UTF-8'`.

Any idea to why the original encoding did not work?

Comment: Oh!  It looks like the problematic character (`-<c0>`) is in the filename. I've updated the jpmam1 version of pisar to correct it, so now it will potentially/hopefully work without having to change your locale (install using `devtools::install_github("jpmam1/pisar")`). Can you please test it when you get a chance @IllimarRekand? Thanks :)